# smtp pro run self test error messages

Tags: magento-1.9, smtp

I am using **SMTP PRO** in  **Magento 1.9.**  When I click **"run self-test"**, I am getting messages

**SMTP** Pro Self Test Results
Sending a test email to your contact form address: **abc@xyz.com** from **aa@xyz.com**. Unable to send a test email.

**Exception message was:** Could not open socket
Please check the user guide for frequent error messages and their solutions.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.

Please Help me ...thank you

Comment: make sure credentials are correct and add real email address instead of test mail address

Comment: 1. Enable open_ssl php extension
2. Download cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
3. Specify its path in php.ini e.g: openssl.cafile="E:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.19/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"  finally 1. Make sure your gmail is allowing low secure apps to sign in, you can turn it on here:https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure sending mail option is Enable in backend.

to check it, go to **System > Configuration > System > Mail Sending Settings** in backend.

and set `Disable Email Communication` option to `No` and then check self run test.

If this issue still exist then check your SMTP details again.